# ActiveRecord referencing model attribute from symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Does anyone know if/how you can reference an attribute of an ActiveRecord model when updating a model using a symbol? I have the code below, which updates my `SocialMediaPost` model where `call[:model_attribute]` is a symbol equal to `:facebook_like_count`.

I want to do something like this:

```
SocialMediaPost.find(id).update_columns(call[:model_attribute]: resp.size)
```

That is functionally equivalent to this:

```
SocialMediaPost.find(id).update_columns(facebook_like_count: resp.size)
```

Note: I need to use `update_columns` for this particular task to bypass all my `before_save`, `after_save`, and `after_commit` callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SocialMediaPost.find(id).update_columns(call[:model_attribute].to_sym => resp.size)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that

```ruby
{ name: value }
```

is a special shortcut notation you **can** use for maps where the keys are symbols. It is equivalent to the following notation

```ruby
{ :name => value }
```

If you use anything else than a symbol you **must** use the "hash rocket" notation, e.g.

```
"name" => value
```

So in your case you can use

```
SocialMediaPost.find(id).update_columns(call[:model_attribute] => resp.size)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I marked Yang's answer though since he had it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#to_sym`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_sym):

```
call[:model_attribute].to_sym
```